# Losing "+" in phone numbers , when converting csv to txt in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Phone number "+49374425070" is getting converted to "49374425070.0" when i try to use "to_csv".

```
source.to_csv('CVV'+'_source.txt',sep = '\t', index = False ,encoding='utf-8',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

import pandas as pd
import csv


#Source
source = pd.read_csv('source2.csv') #source csv name
source.to_csv('CVV'+'_source.txt',sep = '\t', index = False ,encoding='utf-8',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)#float_format='%.0f'

print('archive.txt and source.txt generated')
```

Comment: you should convert phone number as string not int or float

Comment: Use the `pd.read_csv('source2.csv', dtype={'tel_column_name': 'str'})` (just fill in your real column name) or (if there are no numeric values at all in the csv) `..., dtype='str'` to force pandas to not consider the column as numeric. If it even treats it as a `float` like @frankegoesdown suggested, then good luck, if you try to call someone :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to read the column as a string rather than int_64. To do this, use something like this:

```
read_csv('sample.csv', dtype={'phone': str})
```

This will work in Pandas >= 0.9.1.

Comment: you're welcome, just accept the answer so its set as closed :)